# Stack view is too big for the objects inside

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistackview

Well I just started working with Stack views. Lets say I have 3 UILabels that I want to fill all over the width of the superview, horizontally placed. I now see that the last UILabel isn't placed really to the edge of the screen, but the first UILabel is placed correctly. When I click on the Stack View I see that the Stack View is placed correctly, but when I click on the last UILabel it isn't really on the edge of the Stack View. So my question is what am I doing wrong? I tried all different options like fill equally etc. The result of this is that there is a tiny space left on the edge of the screen on iPhone SE and a bigger space of the screen on the iPhone 7. I am not using constrains to margins. I can update this question with pictures if you can not understand what I am meaning.

Picture of which shows that the size of the stack view is stretching to the edges. However, I am also getting the error the the labels inside are missing the X position or width, why is this needed? https://postimg.org/image/49hl5gmuh/

This picture shows that the score of player 4 (the last object in the stack view) doesn't reach the edge of the stack view
https://postimg.org/image/hxj0xvfn5/

Comment: "I can update this question with pictures if you can not understand what I am meaning."  - pls :)

Comment: I did it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It works if your settings for the stack view are correct (the dark lines at the outside are the shadow of the simulator, so you can see the right and left labels are right against the edge):

[image]

I used Equal Spacing, and the stack view itself has constraints pinning its edges to the edges (not the margins!) of the superview.

Comment: Equal spacing causes that the uilabels will go over each other at iPhone SE screen. I am using the constrains of the stack view: center X, equal width to: View, top space to: Superview equals 2, and the height is 21. I am currently using Fill Equally. edit: when removing center X and adding the pins 0 and 0 (leading and trailing), auto layout is asking me to set constrains for the labels inside that stack view...

Comment: "I am currently using Fill Equally" But that is the problem. If you add background colors to your labels, you will see that you _are_ filling equally — and so the right edge of the last label is empty because it is left-justified!